# Book layout software

Tags: publishing

I have a requirement to create a small book. It's about 30-50 pages, and contains text and color photos.

What software is generally used to design such a book?

I'm currently using Corel Draw but I find it to be clunky.

Is there anything better that people are using for this type of task?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest Adobe InDesign, QuarkXPress, MS Word or OpenOffice Writer, depending on how technical you need the layout to be.

Answer (score 1):

To get good color reproduction, you need something with CMYK support. That means no MS-Word or Open Office. I got best results with LaTeX and Framemaker, but Framemaker had six years of stagnation before being resurrected 3 years ago.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with using Corel products, they have another piece of software called [Ventura Publisher](http://www.corel.com/servlet/Satellite/ca/en/Product/1152105061811) which may have come with your Corel bundle.

> When it comes to business publishing,
>   Corel Ventura® 10 is as powerful as it
>   gets. It's the only tool you need for
>   transforming long, complex documents —
>   including XML files — into highly
>   formatted and visually rich
>   publications.
>
> Enhanced stability and compatibility
>   keep your workflow smooth, while
>   powerful formatting tools help ensure
>   polished documents. Update multiple
>   tables quickly with new table tags.
>   Enjoy more flexibility with XML import
>   support. And work faster with improved
>   PDF and printing options.

[image]

If you're comfortable with learning some syntax, [LaTeX](http://www.latex-project.org/) is another excellent option. LaTeX is free and there is a ton of documentation for it available on the net. I'd recommend it if you want the finest control over the layout of your book.

Comment: Yeah, I've used latex for doing reports. I don't think that would work here because a lot of visual design with photos is needed.

Answer (score 0):

[Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/) is the leading free, open-source desktop publisher.