# Which software is used to publish a book of size A5

Tags: publishing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Book layout software](https://superuser.com/questions/94165/book-layout-software)

I have some text and i want to make book of A5 size.
The fonts is also not english its in my own language.

Which software should i use to make a soft copy.

And how can i give them to print shop so that they can print with some images and required fonts which will not be in their computer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write your book on whatever pleases you, and publish it as either .pdf or .ps. Most print shops will accept both. .djvu format is an option, but more rare then the above two.

As far as printing goes, yes, as someone suggested, you could edit your book in A5 format, which is somewhat unusual (not the format *per se* but the fact that books are not usually printed in that format ...).

If it is not a professionally done job on a larger scale (thousands of copies printed on large offset machines), I would suggesting editing your book in A4 format, and then when printing by using zoom function/print to fit printing it to A5 format. It is a standard option in Adobe Acrobat.

If the print shop has paper cutting capabilities, they may use the option to print both sides on paper, and then just cut it in two prior to binding it. Done it, works out very nicely.

After that you just bind it, and you're done.

Comment: i want to print only 2-3 copies only . i think thats the good idea.
basically i want colored border around text on all pages with page number and current title of chapter. So should i make it in MS Word in A4 size and print pdf. Then printing company can make various sizes

Comment: Oh, for 2-3 copies there is absolutely no problem. Yes, do what you want in Word, set it up as you like (border, pg number, current title of chapter - Word has features that enable all of that), and bring it up to them. They'll print it and bind it. No problem at all.

Comment: I know that page number feature is in header (in Word2007), chapter title is related to sections ... don't know where border is since I never use those, but it's somewhere in there.

Comment: So it means , i have to make fonts very bigger so that when they are reduced they look ok

Comment: @Mirage - No, in MS Word, you can select your document size under the "Document Properties" menu or ribbon. Set your document to A5 size, then write it. If it's already written in A4, set it to A5, then fix the formatting before sending it to a printer in pdf format. If there are any more questions, ask your printer, since their requirements will override any advice given here. That's to say that whatever advice we give you, you will eventually need to provide whatever format they tell you to send them.

Comment: @Mirage - Also, by editing your document at A5 size, you can set your fonts correctly.

Answer (score 1):

If it is only text, a normal word processor should be up to the challenge, if you're thinking of a nice layout you should consider desktop publishing (DTP) software (e.g. **[Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/)**, which is free and open source).

Most print shops accept PDF, so print the result as PDF (e.g. with **[CutePDF](http://www.cutepdf.com/products/cutepdf/Writer.asp)**) and have it printed and bound.

Answer (score 0):

You should talk to your printer about what formats they accept. It tends to vary from printer to printer. You could try and use something like MS Publisher or Pages though these can be expensive to purchase.

Some printers will accept pdf files so you might be able to just get away with a cheap job like setting your page size to A5 in your word-processor and printing to PDF

Answer (score 0):

pdf or ps should be a good option to give it to print.
As for the actual creation of the book you might consider using LaTeX, but for simple text even Word or similar program could do the job.